# SpriteKit touchesMoved is erratic when used in a subclass of SKSpritenode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm subclassing SKSpritenode (In Swift) to create coloured blocks that can then be dragged around the scene. The subclass is SoundNode.

```
import SpriteKit

class SoundNode: SKSpriteNode {

init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touch began")
    }

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touches moved")
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
        }   
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
    self.position = touchLocation
    }


override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("touch ended")
    }


}
```

in GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addSoundBlock()
  }


  func addSoundBlock() {
    let soundBlock = SoundNode()
    soundBlock.position = CGPoint(x: 800, y: 800)
    addChild(soundBlock)
    }
}
```

This works, sort of.

soundBlock is added, and can be dragged around the scene. But it flickers and sometimes disappears.
I have tried other methods within touchesMoved, none of them effected the jerkiness.

If I don't subclass the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded, and implement the actions in GameScene, then the dragging becomes smooth. But future plans hinge on being able to subclass these.

Xcode 8, Swift 3, iOS10

Comment: Hey Rich, you get to the bottom of this? I'm considering something similar.

Comment: my gut feeling is that this: `let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)` should refer to the touch location in the frame of the scene, rather than in the frame of the sprite (self).

Comment: I have only been able to fix it by not subclassing the behaviour.  So I moved the touchesBegan and other action to GameScene.swift      This works but it feels messy.  Not sure if I should leave this open or post it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class method to handle the movement of the subclass of SKSpriteNode, in my case 'Player' and passed it the location of the touch within GameScene.swift.

Class method declaration in Player.swift:

```
    func movePlayer(location: CGPoint) {
        //movement code
    }
```

Calling the function in GameScene.swift:

```
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

         guard let location = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
         player.movePlayer(location: location)

    }
```

Somewhat cleaner, I suppose. And allows for further subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, with a subclass of SKNode as the child element of a SKNode on the GameScene parent:

1. GameScene (top level parent)
2. GridNode (SKNode subclass, child of `GameScene`)
3. TileNode (SKNode subclass, child of `GridNode`)

The `touchesMoved` method called from `TileNode` was returning erratic values for `touches.first.location` when swiping in a straight line:

```
134.6666259765625
-42.33331298828125
133.6666259765625
-41.6666259765625
132.33331298828125
-40.6666259765625
131.6666259765625
-40.33331298828125
```

I believe the issue stems from `TileNode`'s size (and therefore position) being effectively 0 from the perspective of the `GameScene`.

I solved it like this (in the `TileNode` class):

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
    guard let parent = self.parent as? GridNode else { return }
    let movingPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: parent)

    ...
}
```

**Note** `touch.location(in: parent)` vs. `touch.location(in: self)`. `GridNode` has a set position in its `GameScene` parent, whereas `TileNode` does not.

Now `movingPoint` returns smooth values, without the jitter.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I have sometimes found inconsistent appearance of a sprite (i.e. sometimes visible, sometimes not) when zPosition is not set to ensure that the sprite is in front of other nodes.  I think this might be because if two nodes have the same zPosition, then there isn't a way for the graphics engine to ensure which one is on top.
Try setting zPosition to some number which ensures it's in front of other nodes.
For example after:

```
soundBlock.position = CGPoint(x: 800, y: 800)
```

add:

```
soundBlock.zPosition = 1000
```

I haven't tried running this but may be worth a go?